# MYSQL One connection for one class

Tags: java, mysql

I am learning about MySQL database and I cannot quite understand one concept. Lets say there are two methods in the same class as the one shown below. Now, do i have to use Connection connect = dbConnection.getDBConnection(); in each method or is there a different way to declare one connection and use it across multiple methods?:

```
private void setUpdateButton(ActionEvent event) {
    try{
        Connection connect = dbConnection.getDBConnection();
        Statement stmt = connect.createStatement();


        if(txtID.getText().trim().isEmpty()||txtFirstName.getText().trim().isEmpty() || txtSecondName.getText().trim().isEmpty() ||
                txtGender.getText().trim().isEmpty() || txtAge.getText().trim().isEmpty() || txtHomeAddress.getText().trim().isEmpty() || txtPhoneNumber.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
            showAlert("Invalid Input!", "All fields need to be populated before updating.");
        }else {
               String sqlQuery ="update student_information set Age ='"+Integer.parseInt(txtAge.getText())+"',Name ='"+txtFirstName.getText()+"',Surename='"+txtSecondName.getText()
            +"',Gender='"+txtGender.getText()+"',Address='"+txtHomeAddress.getText()+"',PhoneNumber='"+txtPhoneNumber.getText()+"'where ID="+Integer.parseInt(txtID.getText());
               stmt.executeLargeUpdate(sqlQuery);
               setTxtArea();
               showConfAlert("Update Completed!", "Record has been updated!");
```

Comment: You could make the **connect** object Class global but then you need to realize that the database connection will remain open until you close it with a **connect.close()**.  You of course will also need to remove all the connect.close() from your methods. You should **always** close your database connection when you're done with it. I personally like the way your doing it right now but then again...it all depends upon what your doing.

Comment: Does that mean using Connection connect = dbConnection.getDBConnection(); in every method to connect is the correct way of doing it? It seems weird for me that i need to create a new connection in every method. Thanks for your response

Comment: In my opinion....Yes. And the connection should be closed (along with the ResultSet  and Statement objects) in a finally{} block to release database resources. It really all depends upon what you're doing during your database session.

Comment: You can run multiple queries on one connection, yes.

Comment: How do I use one connection rather then creating a new one each time? Thanks for response guys.

Comment: Just place `Connection connect = dbConnection.getDBConnection();` directly under your Class constructor. This will then make the **connect** object class global to all methods within that class.

Answer (score 0):

Creating connections is a costly operation, so I think you should open the connection at the application startup, and close it on exit.

If your program is not multi thread you would be fine with a simple global object, otherwise other strategies should be used.

You can create a singleton for your app with a method returning the connection.

```
public class App {
    private static App self;

    private Connection connection;

    private App(){
    }

    public synchronized App getInstance(){
        if(self == null){
            self = new App();
        }
        return self;
    }


    public synchronized Connection getConnection()throws SQLException {
        if(connection==null || !isValid(connection)){
            // Create a new connection 
        }
        return connection;
    }

    private boolean isValid(Connection conn) {
        // Check if the connection is valid otherwise return false 
        return false;
    }


    public static synchronized void close(){
        try{
            self.connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e){
            // Swallow exception
        } finally {
            self = null;
        }
    }

}
```

You can get the connection anywhere like this:

```
Connection conn = App.getInstance().getConnection();
```

You should make sure to close the connection on exit, maybe with a shutdown hook.

You could also, create a wrapper around your connection that forwards all connection methods to the original connection , with the exception of close that marks the connection *available* , this way you create something like 1 connection pool.

If the connection is available you return it otherwise you either wait or throw or do what is most appropriate for your application.